# Which websites provide real-time updated Jupyter notebooks for Python teaching?

Tags: python

Often, I find it useful to teach some Python to students. In-person classes are easy in this regard, I can just go to [colab.research.google.com](https://colab.research.google.com/) and show them the concepts there. (It requires no technical knowledge to use it, that's why I prefer that over locally-run Jupyter notebooks.)

Despite the claim that it is good for collaborative working, it does not update live as I write content in those notebooks, as Google Jamboard would, for example.

Are there websites that provide Jupyter notebooks (with Python 3 backend) which I could use to work with students in real-time? By real-time, I mean that I want my students to see what I have written in a cell within a second at most.

Comment: TIL Jupyter notebooks can be updated in real time.  I had no idea.  The closest thing I've seen to what you're asking for is [cocalc](https://cocalc.com/doc/jupyter-notebook.html), but it doesn't appear to have pre-made lessons.  Hopefully someone else will pipe in with an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I don't need the lessons to be pre-made, I can write the code while talking to the students :)

Comment: In that case, I'll convert my comment into an answer!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not terrifically familiar Jupyter notebooks.  I've only used them a few times myself, and I didn't realize that any of them could support simultaneous editing as you've described.

However, [cocalc](https://cocalc.com/doc/jupyter-notebook.html) appears to be able to do what you need, though it is a paid tool.  (Personally, I enjoy supporting companies that make really good tools, though I understand that others may feel differently about using paid software.)

Comment: I have just tested. It works with about a second of lag (for 2 tabs on same machine). I did not sign up. There is a bit of screen wasted telling me "sign up to be able to save work". (only tested for about 1 minute, nothing complex)